# How does the c_if instruction work in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-circuit

The c_if instruction can be used to make the result of a measurement saved to a classical register adjust whether a gate is or is not performed. How does the c_if instruction obtain the measurement result from the classical register and determine whether it meets the conditions?
[image]

Like in the picture, how does c_if instruction get the measurement result in creg_c?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The line `circ.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])` measures the qubit `qreg_q[0]` and stores the result in the classical bit `creg_c[0]`. Since **this bit is classical**, it is easy for a computer to read it to know whether the gate should be applied.

Comment: If instead of appling a gate based on the value of creg_c[0], I want to do a classical addition based on the value of creg_c [0], for example, if the value of creg_c [0] is 1, calculate a = a +1. How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

The complete version of your example is this:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(2, name='q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(1, name='c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)

circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])
circuit.x(qreg_q[1]).c_if(creg_c, 0)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

The value of `c` is a flip coin of `1` or `0`. If it is one, `X` will be applied to the other qubit.

If based on the classical value of `c`, you want to perform a classical operation, like `a = a +1`, then no operation is performed on the quantum circuit.

You can move the quantum result to your classical Python world with `execute`

```
from qiskit import BasicAer, execute

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(1, name='q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(1, name='c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)

circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_c[0])

result = execute(circuit, BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots=1).result().get_counts()

a = 3
if result.get('0', False):
    a = a + 1
print(a)
```