# Getting Measurement Values from ClassicalRegister in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, measurement, quantum-circuit

Is it possible to get the value of a measurement stored in the classical register in qiskit? Say that I have

```
q = QuantumRegister(9)
c = ClassicalRegister(9)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
```

And I measure each qubit as

```
circuit.measure(q[i],c[i])
```

Then what I see when I print out any value in `c[i]` is `Clbit(ClassicalRegister(9, 'c3'), 0)`. I'm wondering how I can see what the actual value of the individual classical bit is? Can I do it without having to first execute the job (i.e. so that I can utilize the value in a mid-circuit measurement scenario)?

Comment: Do you mean to extract classical bit values after execution of the job?

Comment: @MartinVesely No, I mean can we get the values stored in the classical register without having to execute the job. Like, if I wanted to perform operations dependent on the classical register before executing

Comment: Qiskit allows you to perform mid-circuit measurement and to act accordingly to what was measured: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28010/how-does-the-c-if-instruction-work-in-qiskit However, you do need to execute a job to get the values. Think about it: the classical register contains the result of a measurement performed on a quantum state. In order for this state to have been created, it is of course required that a job has been run.